# How can unsafe-inline in the src-script directive in CSP expose a website to XSS attacks?

Tags: content-security-policy

How can unsafe-inline in the src-script directive in CSP exposes a website to XSS attacks?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Inline script is typically the initial step in an XSS attack, where some script is placed on a page, either reflected or stored. It may then download additional script code if additional instructions are needed.

Without a CSP or in a CSP without default-src or script directives, inline script is allowed.

Allowing unsafe-inline weakens the default security restrictions imposed by CSP by allowing the most common XSS attack vector. Your CSP will then not be able to prevent XSS attacks, only reduce the scope of them by restricting where script can be downloaded from and make it harder to exfiltrate data.